# error on non-object while using pdo

Tags: php, pdo

I keep getting an error `Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /home... on line 44`

Line 44 is the last `$statement`. `$db` is injected, don't know why it doesn't work. the query above works fine.

```
public $userinfo = array();
public $time_now = 0;
public $session_time = 3600;
public $db;
public $config;

public function __construct($db,$config)
{
    $this->userinfo['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $this->time_now = time();
    $this->db = $db;
    $this->config = $config;
    $this->userinfo['userid'] = 0;
    $this->userinfo['level'] = 0;
}
function validate_user()
{
    if ($temp_userid = $_SESSION['userid'] > 0)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT userid,level,name,email,lastactivity  
                FROM user 
                WHERE userid = ? LIMIT 1";

        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute(array($temp_userid));
        $sid_row = $statement->fetchObject();

        if ($sid_row)
        {
            $this->userinfo['userid'] = $sid_row->userid;
            $this->userinfo['level'] = $sid_row->level;
            $this->userinfo['name'] = $sid_row->name;
            $this->userinfo['email'] = $sid_row->email;

            if ($this->time_now-600 > $sid_row->lastactivity)
            {
                $sql = "UPDATE user SET lastactivity = ? WHERE userid = ? LIMIT 1";
                $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $statement->execute(array($this->time_now,$this->userinfo['userid']));
            }
        }
    }....................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try **$statement = $this->db->execute** ?

Comment: I get this `Call to undefined method PDO::execute() `

Comment: Yeahh true... execute is the statement of prepare. Hmm.. Did you try using bindParam ?

Comment: It was working find on my old server. Is it installed correctly? http://screensnapr.com/e/ZpRjTY.png

PDO works fine when I do simple queries. I'm baffled.

Comment: It may be the file charset. It happen sometime to me in Notepad++. I write something, I see perfect code and when I run the script in the browser, PHP give me an error. I have to switch from ASCII to UTF-8 or UTF-8 to ASCII to see it (no convert, change encoding style). So then I see a wrong symbol, I just then rewrite the line from nothing and it work... If it's not that, I am like you... no idea :(